# Want to understand output of nm for static variable which are local to function

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I declared two static variables. One is global and the other is local to a main function. After that I did `nm a.out`

**output:**

```
0000000000000000 l     O .data  0000000000000004 gloBAL_a   <<<<< static outside main

0000000000000004 l     O .data  0000000000000004 local_b.2127 <<< static inside main
```

what does  .2127 mean ?

Comment: `gloBAL_a and  local_b`

Comment: Probably nothing except a relative offset, or maybe sequence number, for the variable within the .o file.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable at file scope, it will have an unique identifier `gloBAL_a`. But when you declare local static variable in local scope, it can use the same name as another variable allocated elsewhere.

The compiler therefore uses something called "name mangling", to ensure that the variable name used internally is always unique. That is, it adds a dot and a serial number after the variable name.

You could try to name both variables the same name and you should see the same kind of name mangling for both of them.